# ifstream skips numbers and just writes 0

Tags: c++, text-files, ifstream

I am trying to read and assign numbers from a text file to double so I can use it to calculate how much it costs. 
I tried using:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
struct info
{
string pavadinimas;
double benzinas, dujos, sumad, sumab,km, dujk,benzk, suma;

};
void skaityk (int &n, info S[], double dujk, double benzk, double km)
{
    ifstream fd ("Duomenys.txt");
    fd>>dujk >>benzk>> km;
    fd>> n;
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
         fd.ignore(80, '\n');
         char simb [15];
         fd.get (simb, 15);
         S[i].pavadinimas=simb;
         fd>>S[i].benzinas>>S[i].dujos;
    }
    fd.close();
}
```

the text file contents are:

```
8.4 10.1 500 3
Orlen          4.56 2.32
Neste          4.66 2.43
Saurida        4.65 2.44
```

and I want to take the 3 first numbers and  count the but they just turn up as 0 no matter what I do and whithout `fd>>dujk >>benzk>> km;` it messes up so I am realy confused on what to do
I got asked for the full code so here it is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
struct info
{
string pavadinimas;
double benzinas, dujos, sumad, sumab,km, dujk,benzk, suma;

};
void skaityk (int &n, info S[], double &dujk, double &benzk, double &km)
{
    ifstream fd ("Duomenys.txt");
    fd>>dujk >>benzk>> km;
    fd>> n;
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
         fd.ignore(80, '\n');
         char simb [15];
         fd.get (simb, 15);
         S[i].pavadinimas=simb;
         fd>>S[i].benzinas>>S[i].dujos;
    }
    fd.close();
}
void rasyk (int n , info S[], double suma)
{
    ofstream fr ("Rezultatai.txt");
    fr<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<suma<<endl;
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    fr<<S[i].pavadinimas<<fixed<<setw(8)<<setprecision(2)<<S[i].sumad;
};
double sumuokd (int n,info S[])
{
   double s=0;
   for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
   {
       S[i].sumad=S[i].dujk*S[i].km*S[i].dujos;
   }
};
int main()
{
    int n;
    info S[101];
    double dujk, benzk, km;
    skaityk(n,S, dujk, benzk, km);
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
       cout<<S[i].pavadinimas<<fixed<<setw(8)<<setprecision(2)<<S[i].benzinas<<fixed<<setw(8)<<setprecision(2)<<S[i].dujos<<endl<<S[i].sumad<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[with the line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W31Ws.png)
[Without the line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnPDM.png)

Comment: you can read 3 values at a go including the string. I am not sure about the ignore and fd.get thing, may be that's causing issue.

Comment: There are plenty of possible errors. Can you post the main function as well?

Comment: ill add the whole code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the tables in C++ starts with 0 so all your for loops should be changed from:

```
for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
```

into:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
```

Then if you want to get the `dujk, benzk, km` values from the function, you need to use references (&) before each value that you want to be passed from funtion:

```
void skaityk (int &n, info S[], double & dujk, double & benzk, double & km)
```

The code after following modifications will output

```
Orlen             4.56    2.32
Neste             4.66    2.43
Saurida           4.65    2.44
```

Last but not least, it is better to use std::vector instead of plain array.

Comment: Thanks but sadly I still haven't learned vectors so I don't know how to use them

Comment: OK. Does my answer answers your question?

Comment: It still writes 0.00

Comment: Im trying to calculate 3 nubers in double sumuokd and  S[i].sumad=S[i].dujk*S[i].km*S[i].dujos; but it still  writes 0  link to my resluts https://imgur.com/0bUTAFK

Comment: Please update your code, as sumuokd prints nothing and also it should return something, so the code you posted won't compile.